# Select2 reversing letters as I type on Android phone

Tags: android, google-chrome, jquery-select2

I have a website that uses jquery-select2 multiple select for inputs on some of the forms. They work great on multiple desktop browsers, and on the iPhone. But when I use them on an Android phone, I get a very weird bug. For the multiple select, I can type to search for items. Select2 reverses part of the letters that I type. I have to type the *last* letter of the word first, and then the rest of the word. So to search for "John" in the select2 box, I have to type, "nJoh" on my Android keyboard.

I have tried the Samsung keyboard and the Google keyboard and both have this issue, so it's not the keyboard. I have also tried multiple browsers on the Android phone, and all have this issue, so it's not a browser-specific bug. Using a *desktop* browser, even if I shrink it to narrow width to emulate a phone viewport, there is no issue.

Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot or solve this issue?

Apologies if this is a duplicate post. I have searched quite a bit and have not found a solution.